# css @media query with bootstrap

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to achieve if the screen is pc user `width:880px;` if it is mobile use `width: inherit;`, how do i get this using the **@media query**.

```
@media all and (width: 880px) {
    .colm_6_container {
        width: inherit;

    }
}
```

My div class is 'colm_6_container'.

Comment: Use `max-width` or `min-width` if you want to apply the css for users with resolution 880px or higher instead.

Comment: Your question is not clear...Using @media query you can design for that screen separately..

Comment: i want the width of the div to be 880px when the user is not using mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

```
//ipad and desktop

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .colm_6_container{ 
        width: 880px; 
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.